# Upgraded to Rails 4, rspec causing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, ruby-on-rails-4

Followed the railscasts on upgrading to rails 4 to complete the process, in doing so, I have broken my user test suite.

user_spec.rb :

```
describe User do

    before do
        @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com",
                   password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end

    subject(@user)

    it { should respond_to(:email)}
    it { should respond_to(:password_digest)}
    it { should respond_to(:password)}
    it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation)}
    it { should respond_to(:authenticate)}
end
```

Here is what rspec is spitting out :

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:180:in
`define_method': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
```

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

What could be causing myself to have these issues? Thank you!

UPDATE: user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitivity: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }   
end
```

Comment: Try to remove all tests and leave only block `describe User do; end` (maybe add dummy test to check `it 'foo' do; true.should be_true; end`. Do you have the same error or test is passed?

Comment: It means the problem in one of the test. I suggest to remove all tests and adds them by one - this helps to localize the problem test. I think the problem in this one `password_digest`

Comment: I just left up 'it { should respond_to(:email)}' and it seems to be spewing up the error, I'll add the user class to the main post

Comment: Try to check respond_to from rails console `User.new.respond_to?(:email)`

Comment: try to perform `bundle exec rake test:prepare` (maybe your test DB is not actual)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37397/discussion-between-gotva-and-devo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subject` takes a block as an argument.  You need to say `subject {@user}`.]

You're getting the error you're getting because Ruby is trying to treat `@user` as a `Proc` object.

Comment: Good ol typo...
Thank you so much for catching that!